# How to get equal height columns childs in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

**What I want to achieve:**

1. Equal height columns direct childs, so gaps will be visible between columns (first solution in Codepen but it fails on Safari (Mac)).

   **or (if that's possible)**
2. Equal height Bootstrap columns with visible gaps between them (If I set background color to `col` class divs - gaps are not visible because of padding - you can see that in Codepen).

**What I have tried:**

1. Setting `h-100` class (`height: 100%`) to columns direct childs but it fails on Safari ([see StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521718/why-does-a-percentage-height-work-on-these-elements/)).
2. Using horizontal `margins` on `col` divs instead of `padding` but it breaks Bootstrap's grid system.

### [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/makshh/pen/yPxKRw)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>This is how it should work - fails on Safari (Mac)</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner h-100">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner h-100">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner h-100">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner h-100">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner h-100">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Backgrounds applied to col divs (gaps are not visible because of cols padding)</h3>
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-4 bg">
      <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg">
      <div class="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg">
      <div class="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg">
      <div class="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg">
      <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Bootstrap HTML</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner,
.bg {
  background: #ddd;
}
.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what version of safari are you on? your codepen looks okay in mine (Version 11.0 (11604.1.38.1.7))

Comment: Hmm, I don't have access to my Mac now, I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Fine with me also. You could try `min-height:100%`

Comment: It's probably fixed in 11, I have Safari 10.1 and it doesn't work. I found another solution but I will wait couple of hours for answers ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make i.a. Safari behave, instead of `height`, use Flexbox all the way.

Add `d-flex` to the `col-4` element and `col` to the `inner`.

`d-flex` adds `display: flex` and make the `inner`, based on `align-items` defaults to `stretch`, fill its parent, `col` adds `flex: 1` and make it fill the width.

Stack snippet

```css
h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.col-4 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.inner {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h3>This is how it should work - <strike>fails on Safari (Mac)</strike></h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
      <div class="inner col">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
      <div class="inner col">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
      <div class="inner col">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
      <div class="inner col">Inner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
      <div class="inner col">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. I figured it out but now I'm sure it's the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this class ***align-items-stretch*** along with ***col-4*** for all columns you want to have equal height within the row.

Comment: Strange , I added this class , made some changes to your codepen and could seethe updated equal height ( I had similar issue , and that have i resolved so i am pretty sure this should fix this ).

Comment: I added that class to all `col-4` divs and didn't see any change.

Comment: I am trying to embed the codepen , but could not add it , anyways , This is what all i changed : 1. changed from col-4 to col ( as you have 6 columns , just to make them equal width ) 2. added this class "align-items-stretch"  3. Added some color (use your inner class) , so that i could see them with equal width 4. added mr-1 for margin between columns.

Comment: You can just fork my Codepen, make changes, save and paste a link :)

Comment: check this link , i have changed the section under basic bootsrapt HTML : https://codepen.io/pritesha/pen/pdOVYy

Comment: Ah ok I see, thanks for your work but I'm looking for something different. 1. I want to use `col-x` classes so in case of `col-4` - 4th column wraps to a new row. 2. I want default Bootstrap gaps (30px). 3. As you can see the background in you example is not properly aligned to "Basic Bootstrap HTML" heading.