# Flexbox overlapping text in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

If you load this in IE, you will see that the content of the gray box is extending over to the yellow box, which doesn't happen on other browsers.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.childA {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.childB {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childA">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="childB">
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

- let the gray box (childA) expand according to its content
- let the yellow box (childB) take the remaining height of its parent
- if the content yellow box (childB) has more content, overflow it properly

Can someone help me?

https://jsfiddle.net/6yuh90cd/3/

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: @LiamKenneth 11

Comment: The code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just on an external site. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: [IE struggles with flexbox if it will work for you at all.](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: @Rob It is worrying to see all these comments saying IE can't do Flexbox. Of course it can, and when one **learned its flaws and fixes**, one can make it work for most use cases.

Comment: @LGSon I didn't say IE can't do flexbox but not all IEs can do flexbox and, even then, they don't support the current standard properly.

Comment: @Rob We don't talk about all, the question refer to IE11. And IE11 **does** support the current standard, though in some cases it is buggy (and not the only one that is that), hence one need to learn the workarounds for each browser.

Comment: @LGSon And that is what I said and pointed out with the link.

Comment: Just add `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex items. Then your layout works across browsers. https://jsfiddle.net/6yuh90cd/7/

Comment: @Michael_B That won't work properly (tested on IE11, Chrome, Firefox). `childB` overflow the `parent`. I reopened the question since that dupe link's answer does not solve the question.

Comment: @LGSon, the solution does work. The problem is I posted an unfinished demo by mistake. The `flex-shrink: 0` rule should apply only to `.childA`. https://jsfiddle.net/6yuh90cd/8/

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood how Flexbox work.

Giving the `childB` a height of 100% is not the proper way to say *take the remaining height* (even though some browsers try to make that work).

You should use the [flex item properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property), in this case I used the shorthand `flex`, to tell a flex item to take the available space.

*Updated after question edit*

*This will solve all your expressed 3 requirements:*

- *let the gray box (childA) expand according to its content*
- *let the yellow box (childB) take the remaining height of its parent*
- *if the content yellow box (childB) has more content, overflow it properly*

Stack snippet

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.childA {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.childB {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100%;                        removed  */
  flex: 1;                           /*  added, take the available space  */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childA">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="childB">
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex-shrink: 0` to your overlapping item.

It works across browsers.

(I removed code that isn't necessary.)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.childA {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new; see link reference below */
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.childB {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="childA">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="childB">
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6yuh90cd/9/)

Explanation for `flex-shrink: 0`: [Flex items overlapping in Chrome and IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294014/3597276)

Comment: Since OP wrote _"let the yellow box (childB) take the remaining height of its parent"_, this will not do that, though solve the overlap when text is bigger.

Comment: @LGSon, the question also says: *if the content yellow box (childB) has more content, overflow it properly*

Comment: Maybe I missed something here, but shouldn't all the listed requirements be filled? .. If so, then if there is less content in `childB`, what you suggest won't _take remaining height_.

Comment: If that's ever the case, OP can simply add `flex-grow: 1` to childB. https://jsfiddle.net/6yuh90cd/10/

Comment: Well, that is what I already answered, which solve all 3 req. in one go. .. and OP did actually wrote _**if** the content yellow box (childB) **has** more content_

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work in IE 11 https://jsfiddle.net/6yuh90cd/6/

I gave `childA` class `min-height` of 50%.

```
.childA {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:50%;
}
```

Comment: This only work as the content of `childA` happens to be just that, 50% of the parent. Add a few more lines and the overflow comes back.